# text field cursor issue in chrome

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using following css in my form section.

[image: Screenshot of form fields]

**CSS**

```
.username input{
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 border: 2px solid #DDDDDD;
 border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
 color: #9E9E9E;
 height: 30px;
 width: 330px;
 padding:0px 10px 0px 0px;
 padding-left:10px;
 margin:15px 0px 0px 0px;
 line-height:30px;
}
```

It works fine in all browsers. But in the Chrome, cursor displays in the same height of input tag. I found the solution, if I remove the `line-height` it displays as I want it to. But in IE, the values are in top of the field. I need the solution for this issue.

Please see the [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Etyn/). [It is not good in chrome]

Comment: If you are not opposed to using CSS hacks, then you can target IE8 and below using: `line-height: 30px\9`

Comment: If i have not found a solution, i will use this IE css hack. Thank You so much.

Comment: related https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=47284

Comment: just added an answer that does not use CSS hack to fix this across browsers, see in the answers below

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remove `line-height` attribute from your css class, I think it will help you
updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4Etyn/16/

```
<div class="username">
    <input name="txtFullName" id="txtFullName" type="text" class="user" value="Username" onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Username'" onFocus="if(this.value =='Username' ) this.value=''"  />
</div>

.username input{
    background-color: #FFFFFF; 
    border: 2px solid #DDDDDD;
    border-radius:5px;            
    color: #9E9E9E;
    height: 30px; 
    height: 22px\0/; 
    width: 330px; 
    padding:0px 10px 0px 10px; 
    padding:8px 10px 0px 10px\0/;  
    margin:15px 0px 0px 0px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
:root .username input{
    height: 30px\9;
    padding:0px 10px 0px 10px\9;
}
```

Comment: @BarryKaye can you see my fiddle once, after removing **line-height** attribute it's working fine

Comment: Please check this fiddle in IE8.

Comment: No. Your css works fine in all browser. I have used your idea only.

Comment: Updated for readability: http://jsfiddle.net/4Etyn/14/ (and there was a semicolon missing in your CSS)

Answer (score 6):

#### Up-to-date answer (October 2014)

After playing around & observing what "reference" projects are doing, I realized one thing: we're doing it wrong.

In short: for a solid & clean cross-browser solution one **must not use** `line-height` property to make the `input type="text"` element higher but rather the `padding` property.

---

#### Cross browser issues

As pointed out in the question, browsers interpret the `line-height` property for the `input type="text"` element in different ways.

In this case, for Chrome back then in 2012 & even still now in October 2014 (version 37), it is for the cursor position.

Notice that a related bug was filed in June 2010, https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=47284, but then closed as obsolete (who knows why?): but the provided live bug replication, http://jsbin.com/avefi/2 , still shows the chrome bug at the time of writting (October 2014 - chrome 37).

Note that `Valli69`'s answer also identified `line-height` property as the source of the problem. But then used some rather hacky/dirty/risky IE8 & IE9 fixes (with `\0/` and `\9`). A related question on those technics on [Ie8 CSS Hack - best method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5635829/ie8-css-hack-best-method)

---

#### What about NOT using `line-height` nor `height` property ?

This solution is simple & is even supported by modern and old browsers!

1) Solution in a streamlined example

```
/* 
 * [1] overrides whatever value "line-height" property was given by any other selector
 *     note: make it "line-height: normal !important;" if necessary
 * [2] overrides whatever value "height" property was given by any other selector
 *     note: make it "height: auto !important;" if necessary
 */
.username {
  line-height: normal;  /* [1] */
  height: auto;  /* [2] */
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
<input class="username" type="text" placeholder="Username" />
```

Live demo on http://jsbin.com/yadebenoniro/1/edit?html,css,output (ps. test on IE8 using this url http://jsbin.com/fugegalibuha/1 )

Tested on **Windows OS** on: IE8+, IE11, Chrome 38, & Firefox 32.

2) Solution in the context of the question

```
/*
 * [1] overrides whatever value line-height property was given by any other selector
 *     note: make it "line-height: normal !important;" if necessary
 * [2] overrides whatever value "height" property was given by any other selector
 *     note: make it "height: auto !important;" if necessary
 *
 * [3] use the padding-top, padding-bottom to adjust the height of your input type text
 * [4] keep in mind that when changing the font-size value you will have to adjust the padding top and padding bottom if you want to keep the same height as previously
 */
.username input {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border: 2px solid #DDDDDD;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #9E9E9E;
  height: auto;  /* [2] */
  line-height: normal;  /* [1] */
  margin: 15px 0px 0px 0px; 
  padding: 10px 5px 10px 5px;  /* [3] */
  width: 330px;
  font-size: 20px;  /* [4] */
}
```

Live demo on http://jsbin.com/busobokapama/1/edit?html,css,output (ps. test on IE8 using this url http://jsbin.com/busobokapama/1 )

Tested on **Windows OS** on: IE8+, IE11, Chrome 38, & Firefox 32.

3) Further explanations

This idea came to me after taking a look at [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/): it uses the `height` and `padding` properties only: the `line-height` property is left to its default *brower-provided* value, that is `line-height: normal`.

See by yourself: by inspecting the `input type="text"` elements [on foundation's form component demo page http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/forms.html](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/forms.html)

The only thing is that even "just" using `height` and `padding` seems a problem for IE8 so I decided to even remove the `height` property.

---

#### Conclusion

This solution obviously has the massive advantage of a simple code, that "just works" across all browsers.

But it also has the drawback of NOT letting you have full control of the ***calculated total height***: computed height property (font-size + abitrary number of pixels) + padding-top + padding-bottom + (border-width x 2). The "computed height property" [seems to vary from browsers to browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26426856/html-is-input-box-default-calculated-content-height-different-across-browsers), hence the *"abitrary number of pixels"* naming.

It's up to you to decide what you favor most: simple code or pixel-precise design.

---

#### Resources

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height
- [HTML: is input box default/calculated content height different across browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26426856/html-is-input-box-default-calculated-content-height-different-across-browsers)

Comment: note: I just re-created an issue for Chrome https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=424606 because the original one from 2010 was closed without getting fixed June 2010, see https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=47284

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution that works in the latest versions of Chrome and Firefox, and IE 8 and 9. I didn't test any other browsers because I didn't need to support anything lower than IE 8.

```
<input class="issue" type="text" />
<input class="solution" type="text" />

.issue {
  font-size: 14px;
  height: 44px;
  line-height: 44px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.solution {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  padding: 15px 10px;
}
```

see the live demo on http://jsbin.com/usimeq/1

Edit: Forgot to add that the first input shows the issue, second shows the solution.

Basically just setting the line-height and height to the same as the font size and adjusting the input using padding afterwards to match the intended overall height.

Hopefully it helps anyone else running into this annoying issue.

Comment: Using outside links for source is awkward - what if it goes away or changes?  Ideally, all necessary code should be in the answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, in Firefox 21, the bottoms of some letters are cut off with your solution ('g's for example).

Answer (score 0):

Just replacing `line-height:30px;` with `height:30px;` in your jsFiddle worked for me.

Comment: Yeah it is correct. But in the ie browser the values are going to top the field.

Comment: Not for me in IE9 - which version of IE are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Here's sample css for inputs that will be aligned in IE8 and won't show giant cursor in Chrome.

```
line-height: 14px/*to enclose 13px font, override this if needed*/;
height: 14px/*to enclose 13px font, override this if needed*/;
/*Padding is needed to avoid giant cursor in webkit, which we get if
height = line-height = 22px.*/
padding: 6px 8px;
```