# HTML: is input box default/calculated content height different across browsers

Tags: html, css, forms, input, inputbox

Let's say I have the following code

```css
.username {
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  border: 2px solid #E0E0E0;
}
```

```html
<input class="username" type="text" />
```

See live demo on http://jsbin.com/qudorugoguya/1/edit?html,css,output

I understand that the total height = content height + padding-top + padding-bottom + (border-width x 2).

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#box-dimensions

However, when the `height` property is not assigned a value, it seems like the calculated content height changes from browser to browser. As if it was the result of the font-size + some arbitrary number of pixels proportional to the font-size.

For different browsers `content height` has the following values:

- Chrome 38: 34px
- Firefox 33: 35px
- IE 11: 34.5px
- IE 8: 35px

Note: I got the values from each browsers' built-in developer tool

Is there any way to get consistent values from browser to browser **without setting the `height` property nor the `line-height` property** ?

Comment: Note that CSS Reset & Normalizer have nothing to do with this question. Indeed, even if you add a CSS Reset in this example, the behavior is different, see by yourself on http://jsbin.com/vecugikuyivo/1/edit

Comment: CSS reset/normalization stylesheets are _supposed_ to provide cross-browser consistency in terms of layouts, fonts, sizing, etc. However, I've tried 6 different ones thus far, and while they all succeed at various things, none of them work for this particular problem. So, great question! I've +1'd and favorited it, because I would love to see an answer referencing a specific stylesheet that actually normalizes that input's height across all browsers...

Comment: +1 for testing the 6 different resets/normalizers

Comment: Have your tried CSS reset or CSS normalizer?

Answer (score 1):

Nope, there is no way of doing it besides the methods you have mentioned. Even CSS resets/normalizers will use these methods behind the scenes.

If cross browser content heights are very important to you, I suggest using images.