# input element height larger than font size

Tags: html, css

I have an input element that has a height that is 2px greater than expected.

Below is the css

```css
.input {
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<input class="input">
```

[image]

I would have expected the content height of the input to be 16px due to the font size. For some reason Chrome says my content box is 18px rather than 16px. I even tried to set `line-height: 1` but did not work. Can someone explain this? I'd rather not hard code the height as a solution.

Comment: probably due to 1px border. Considering both up and down sides, it adds additional 2px to height

Comment: Do you have `box-sizing: border-box;` set on all your HTML elements via CSS?

Comment: Thanks for answering. This issue is not about the total heigh.. it's very explicitly about the content box height of the input element.

Comment: Box sizing has not been applied

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28363186/inline-elements-and-line-height

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `box-sizing: content-box` and set `height: 16px`

```css
.input {
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 400px;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  height: 16px;
}
```

```html
<input class="input">
```

Comment: That definitely is a great answer but can you explain why the content box height is 18px when no explicit height is applied

Comment: @alaboudi As i know it's because of browser renderer engine and it's height is different in other browsers. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26426856/html-is-input-box-default-calculated-content-height-different-across-browsers

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll also add this link from the comment on the question. It also refers to a solution from another StackOverflow question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28363186/inline-elements-and-line-height

Answer (score 0):

It says this because of `1px` border but to resolve this add `box-sizing: border-box;` to it.

It will surely solve your issue but if it doesn't let me know in the comments, I will try my best to help you.

Comment: @MahdyAslamy Can you please your html code also, It will help me to assist you better.

Comment: My issue is not about the entire input height, it's the content box height. I just want to understand this behavior

Comment: @alaboudi It's because the width of the content you have written is `400px` and the height is `18px` because of `1px` border on both top and bottom. To resolve  it add `box-sizing: border-box;`  to include **border** and **padding** in **width** and **height**. If it isn't your solution I am really sorry but I can't understand your problem and want you to do me a favour that as soon as you resolve it please let me know I would love to know how you resolved it. And I am sorry for late reply.

Comment: You still have not understood the question. the CONTENT BOX height (not the element height) is 18px. Content height does not include border, padding, nor margins. Please take a look at the image pasted on the question for reference

Comment: @alaboudi I am really sorry but I can't understand the question but please let me know when you resolve your issue, I will check up on you in a couple of days to know whether you resolved it or not. Once again sorry for not able to assist you.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer this. I'm going to mark the other answer is the one im after. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp refer to this image to understand what I mean by content height

Comment: @alaboudi thanks for making me understand your issue and how to solve it and can you do me a favour that if I was able to help you even a bit please upvote my answer, it means a lot to me.